# FavoriteList using Listview ,GSON and SharedPreferences

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-sharedpreferences, gson

I trying to display a list of items with favorites icon. When the list item is long pressed, the item is added to the favorites. When we say the item is added to the favorites, we actually store the list of items in shared preferences mapped to a key.

Android SharedPreferences class does not provide a way to store a List or ArrayList or any collection. In order to store a list (even array, set or any collection) under a key, so converted the list to JSON format using Gson and store it as string. While retrieving convert the JSON string back to list and return it.

but i got an unexpected crash and error !

### MainActivity

```
package com.company.wishlist_2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private Fragment contentFragment;
ProductListFragment pdtListFragment;
FavoriteListFragment  favListFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("content")) {
            String content = savedInstanceState.getString("content");
            if (content.equals(FavoriteListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
                if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FavoriteListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID) != null) {
                    setFragmentTitle(R.string.favorites);
                    contentFragment = fragmentManager
                            .findFragmentByTag(FavoriteListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
                }
            }
        }
        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(ProductListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID) != null) {
            pdtListFragment = (ProductListFragment) fragmentManager
                    .findFragmentByTag(ProductListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
            contentFragment = pdtListFragment;
        }
    } else {
        pdtListFragment = new ProductListFragment();
        setFragmentTitle(R.string.app_name);
        switchContent(pdtListFragment, ProductListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    if (contentFragment instanceof FavoriteListFragment) {
        outState.putString("content", FavoriteListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
    } else {
        outState.putString("content", ProductListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_favorites:
        setFragmentTitle(R.string.favorites);
        favListFragment = new FavoriteListFragment();
        switchContent(favListFragment, FavoriteListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void switchContent(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    while (fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate());

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, tag);

        if (!(fragment instanceof ProductListFragment)) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
        }
        transaction.commit();
        contentFragment = fragment;
    }
}

protected void setFragmentTitle(int resourseId) {
    setTitle(resourseId);
    getActionBar().setTitle(resourseId);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else if (contentFragment instanceof ProductListFragment
            || fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        finish();
    }
}
}
```

### Product

```
package com.company.wishlist_2;

public class Product {

private int id;
private String name;
private String description;
private double price;

public Product() {
    super();
}

public Product(int id, String name, String description, double price) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + id;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Product other = (Product) obj;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Product [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", description="
            + description + ", price=" + price + "]";
}   
}
```

### FavoriteListFragment

```
package com.company.wishlist_2;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FavoriteListFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "favorite_list";

ListView favoriteList;
SharedPreference sharedPreference;
List<Product> favorites;
Activity activity;
ProductListAdapter productListAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activity = getActivity();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_list, container,
            false);

    sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
    favorites = sharedPreference.getFavorites(activity);

    if (favorites == null) {
        showAlert(getResources().getString(R.string.no_favorites_items),
                getResources().getString(R.string.no_favorites_msg));
    } else {

        if (favorites.size() == 0) {
            showAlert(
                    getResources().getString(R.string.no_favorites_items),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.no_favorites_msg));
        }

        favoriteList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_product);
        if (favorites != null) {
            productListAdapter = new ProductListAdapter(activity, favorites);
            favoriteList.setAdapter(productListAdapter);

            favoriteList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {

                }
            });

            favoriteList
                    .setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onItemLongClick(
                                AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

                            ImageView button = (ImageView) view
                                    .findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite);

                            String tag = button.getTag().toString();
                            if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("grey")) {
                                sharedPreference.addFavorite(activity,
                                        favorites.get(position));
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        activity,
                                        activity.getResources().getString(
                                                R.string.add_favr),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                button.setTag("red");
                                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
                            } else {
                                sharedPreference.removeFavorite(activity,
                                        favorites.get(position));
                                button.setTag("grey");
                                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_grey);
                                productListAdapter.remove(favorites
                                        .get(position));
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        activity,
                                        activity.getResources().getString(
                                                R.string.remove_favr),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
    return view;
}

public void showAlert(String title, String message) {
    if (activity != null && !activity.isFinishing()) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                .create();
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);


        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        // activity.finish();
                        getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.favorites);
    getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.favorites);
    super.onResume();
}
}
```

### ProductListAdapter

```
package com.company.wishlist_2;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ProductListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

private Context context;
List<Product> products;
SharedPreference sharedPreference;

public ProductListAdapter(Context context, List<Product> products) {
    super(context, R.layout.product_list_item, products);
    this.context = context;
    this.products = products;
    sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView productNameTxt;
    TextView productDescTxt;
    TextView productPriceTxt;
    ImageView favoriteImg;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return products.size();
}

@Override
public Product getItem(int position) {
    return products.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.productNameTxt = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_pdt_name);
        holder.productDescTxt = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_pdt_desc);
        holder.productPriceTxt = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_pdt_price);
        holder.favoriteImg = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Product product = (Product) getItem(position);
    holder.productNameTxt.setText(product.getName());
    holder.productDescTxt.setText(product.getDescription());
    holder.productPriceTxt.setText(product.getPrice() + "");


    if (checkFavoriteItem(product)) {
        holder.favoriteImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
        holder.favoriteImg.setTag("red");
    } else {
        holder.favoriteImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_grey);
        holder.favoriteImg.setTag("grey");
    }

    return convertView;
}


public boolean checkFavoriteItem(Product checkProduct) {
    boolean check = false;
    List<Product> favorites = sharedPreference.getFavorites(context);
    if (favorites != null) {
        for (Product product : favorites) {
            if (product.equals(checkProduct)) {
                check = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return check;
}

@Override
public void add(Product product) {
    super.add(product);
    products.add(product);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void remove(Product product) {
    super.remove(product);
    products.remove(product);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}   
}
```

### ProductListFragment

```
package com.company.wishlist_2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ProductListFragment extends Fragment implements
    OnItemClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener {

public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "product_list";

Activity activity;
ListView productListView;
List<Product> products;
ProductListAdapter productListAdapter;

SharedPreference sharedPreference;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activity = getActivity();
    sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_list, container,
            false);
    findViewsById(view);

    setProducts();

    productListAdapter = new ProductListAdapter(activity, products);
    productListView.setAdapter(productListAdapter);
    productListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    productListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

private void setProducts() {

    Product product1 = new Product(1, "Dell XPS", "Dell XPS Laptop", 60000);
    Product product2 = new Product(2, "HP Pavilion G6-2014TX",
            "HP Pavilion G6-2014TX Laptop", 50000);
    Product product3 = new Product(3, "ProBook HP 4540",
            "ProBook HP 4540 Laptop", 45000);
    Product product4 = new Product(4, "HP Envy 4-1025TX",
            "HP Envy 4-1025TX Laptop", 46000);
    Product product5 = new Product(5, "Dell Inspiron",
            "Dell Inspiron Laptop", 48000);
    Product product6 = new Product(6, "Dell Vostro", "Dell Vostro Laptop",
            50000);
    Product product7 = new Product(7, "IdeaPad Z Series",
            "Lenovo IdeaPad Z Series Laptop", 40000);
    Product product8 = new Product(8, "ThinkPad X Series",
            "Lenovo ThinkPad X Series Laptop", 38000);
    Product product9 = new Product(9, "VAIO S Series",
            "Sony VAIO S Series Laptop", 39000);
    Product product10 = new Product(10, "Series 5",
            "Samsung Series 5 Laptop", 50000);

    products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    products.add(product1);
    products.add(product2);
    products.add(product3);
    products.add(product4);
    products.add(product5);
    products.add(product6);
    products.add(product7);
    products.add(product8);
    products.add(product9);
    products.add(product10);
}

private void findViewsById(View view) {
    productListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_product);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    Product product = (Product) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(activity, product.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
        int position, long arg3) {
    ImageView button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite);

    String tag = button.getTag().toString();
    if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("grey")) {
        sharedPreference.addFavorite(activity, products.get(position));
        Toast.makeText(activity,
                activity.getResources().getString(R.string.add_favr),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        button.setTag("red");
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
    } else {
        sharedPreference.removeFavorite(activity, products.get(position));
        button.setTag("grey");
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_grey);
        Toast.makeText(activity,
                activity.getResources().getString(R.string.remove_favr),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    super.onResume();
}
}
```

### SharedPreference

```
package com.company.wishlist_2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

import com.google.gson.Gson;


public class SharedPreference {

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "PRODUCT_APP";
public static final String FAVORITES = "Product_Favorite";

public SharedPreference() {
    super();
}


public void saveFavorites(Context context, List<Product> favorites) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    Editor editor;

    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(favorites);

    editor.putString(FAVORITES, jsonFavorites);

    editor.commit();
}

public void addFavorite(Context context, Product product) {
    List<Product> favorites = getFavorites(context);
    if (favorites == null)
        favorites = new ArrayList<Product>();
    favorites.add(product);
    saveFavorites(context, favorites);
}

public void removeFavorite(Context context, Product product) {
    ArrayList<Product> favorites = getFavorites(context);
    if (favorites != null) {
        favorites.remove(product);
        saveFavorites(context, favorites);
    }
}

public ArrayList<Product> getFavorites(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    List<Product> favorites;

    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (settings.contains(FAVORITES)) {
        String jsonFavorites = settings.getString(FAVORITES, null);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Product[] favoriteItems = gson.fromJson(jsonFavorites,
                Product[].class);

        favorites = Arrays.asList(favoriteItems);
        favorites = new ArrayList<Product>(favorites);
    } else
        return null;

    return (ArrayList<Product>) favorites;
}
}
```

### My Error

```
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.wishlist_2/com.company.wishlist_2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.company.wishlist_2.MainActivity.setFragmentTitle(MainActivity.java:100)
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.company.wishlist_2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309) 
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157) 
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289) 
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317) 
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
01-17 14:14:53.599 8584-8584/com.company.wishlist_2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is line number `100` in MainActivity.java ?

Comment: the error happen at setFragmentTitle(int) method, why are you setting the title twice? once setTtitle and the other for the actionbar? I say comment these two lines and try again to make sure you JSON thing working right